# Order Column Family with different id by date

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I use the following CQL queries to create a table and write data, the problem is that the data in my table are not organized by date order.

I would like to have them organized by date without having to put the same id.

To create table :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sk1_000.data(id varchar, date_serveur timestamp ,nom_objet varchar, temperature double, etat boolean , PRIMARY KEY (id, date_serveur)) with clustering order by (date_serveur DESC);
```

To insert :

```
INSERT INTO sk1_000.data(id, date_serveur,nom_objet, temperature, etat) VALUES ('"+ uuid.v4() +"', '1501488930499','Raspberry_pi', 22.5, true) if not exists ;
```

Here is the output :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Cassandra, the clustering key guarantees sort order for a given partition key and not across different partitioning key(s).

To achieve what you are looking for "sort by date across all keys", you will have to redesign the table to have date_serveur as partitioning key and id as clustering column. But guess what you can't directly query based on an id with this table design.

Comment: Any questions on the answer provided, otherwise pls remember to accept/upvote